# Please give me examples to help me better understand these different type declarations in C?

Tags: c, pointers, types

I summarized some common C type declarations, now I want to know some solid example, e.g. how to initialize them and how to use them.

Some examples are already given, but some still waiting for good examples.

【 `int p[3];     int *p[3];      int p[][3];    int (*p)[3];     int *(p[3]);      int (*p[8])[5];` 】

【`char p[3];     char *p[3];     char p[][3];     char (*p)[3];     char *(p[3]);      char (*p[8])[5];` 】

【`int **p;    char **p;`】

```
int p[3]; 
//p is array of 3 int.
```

example:

```
int contestants[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

-

```
char p[3];
//p is array of 3 characters.
```

example:

```
char cards[] = "JQK";
```

-

```
 int *p[3];
//p is array of 3 pointers to int.
```

example:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
int z = 3;
int *a1[3] = {&x, &y, &z}; //array of pointer to int
printf (" &x = %p, a1[0] = %p\n" , &x, a1[0]);
printf ("%d %d %d\n" , *a1[0], *a1[1], *a1[2]); //1 2 3
```

-

```
int p[][3];
//p is array of array of 3 int.
```

example:

```
int data1[2][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

-

```
char *p[3];
//p is array of 3 pointers to char.
```

example:

```
char *juices[] = { "dragonfruit", "waterberry", "sharonfruit", "uglifruit",
"rumberry", "kiwifruit", "mulberry", "strawberry", "blueberry",
"blackberry", "starfruit" };
char *names_for_dog[] = {"Bowser", "Bonza", "Snodgrass"};
```

-

```
char p[][3];
//p is array of array of 3 char.
```

example:

```
char tracks[][80] = { "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
"Newark, Newark - a wonderful town", "Dancing with a Dork",
"From here to maternity", "The girl from Iwo Jima", };
```

-

```
int (*p)[3];
//p is pointer to array of 3 ints.
```

example:

```
int data1[2][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
int (*a2)[3] = data1;//pointer to int[3]
printf("%d %d\n" , a2[0][1], a2[1][2]);//2 6
```

-

```
char (*p)[3]; 
//p is pointer to array of 3 char.
```

example:
************I need a good example here*****************

-

```
int *(p[3]); is equivalent to int *p[3]; 
//p is array of 3 pointers to int.
```

-

```
char *(p[3]); is equivalent to char *p[3];
//p is array of 3 pointers to char.
```

-

```
int (*p[8])[5]; 
//p is array of 8 pointers to array of 5 ints.
```

example:

```
int data2[3][4] = { {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {9,10,11,12}};
int (*a3[3])[4] = { &data2[0], &data2[1], &data2[2] };//array of pointer to int[4]
printf("%d %d %d\n" , (*a3[0])[2], (*a3[1])[0], (*a3[2])[3]);//3 5 12
```

-

```
char (*p[8])[5]; 
//p is array of 8 pointers to array of 5 char.
```

example:
************I need a good example here*****************

-

```
int **p;
//p is pointer to pointer to int
```

example:
************I need a good example here*****************

-

```
char **p;
//p is pointer to pointer to char
```

example:
************I need a good example here*****************

Comment: `int *a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };`.. does not seem that's what you want.

Comment: Not clear what you want.

Comment: I've summarized, I think now it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int z = 3;
    int *a1[3] = {&x, &y, &z};//array of pointer to int
    printf("&x = %p, a1[0] = %p\n", &x, a1[0]);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", *a1[0], *a1[1], *a1[2]);//1 2 3

    int data1[2][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
    int (*a2)[3] = data1;//pointer to int[3]
    printf("%d %d\n", a2[0][1], a2[1][2]);//2 6

    int data2[3][4] = { {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {9,10,11,12}};
    int (*a3[3])[4] = { &data2[0], &data2[1], &data2[2] };//array of pointer to int[4]
    printf("%d %d %d\n", (*a3[0])[2], (*a3[1])[0], (*a3[2])[3]);//3 5 12
    return 0;
}
```